# Sheaf of regular functions on an affine $k$-variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We would like to generalize [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241170/sheaf-of-germs-of-regular-functions-on-an-affine-variety) when the base field $k$ is not necessarily algebraically closed.

We use the definitions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246226/relation-between-a-generalization-of-weils-abstract-varieties-and-algebraic-sch).
Let $X$ be a $k$-closed subset of $\Omega^n$.
Let $I(X) = \{f \in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]| f(p) = 0$ for every $p \in X\}$.
Let $A = k[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I(X)$.
Let $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf of $k$-regular functions on $X$.
Are the following assertions true?

1) Let $x \in X$. $\mathcal{O}_x$ is canonically isomorphic to $A_{\mathfrak{p}_x}$, where $\mathfrak{p}_x = \{f \in A|\ f(x) = 0\}$.

2) Let $f \in A$. $\Gamma(D(f), \mathcal{O}_X)$ is canonically isomorphic to $A_f$, where $D(f) = \{x \in X| f(x) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote so that I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both assertions are true. In fact, $X = \textrm{Spec}(A)$ and then it is a special case of Proposition 2.2, Chapter II of Hartshorns book "Algebraic Geometry".